# Rebase a branch that has already been merged

Tags: git

I have a feature branch that has already been merged (in `M`) but reverted afterwards (in `R`):

```
S---o-o-----M-o-R-o
 \         /
  A-----B-C       ^ master

          ^ feature
```

I want to rebase the `feature` branch onto the current `master` so I get:

```
S---o-o-----M-o-R-o-A'-B'-C'
 \         /
  A-----B-C               ^ new master or new branch
                  ^ old master
          ^ feature
```

This is similar to the process described in the *addendum* of [revert-a-faulty-merge.txt](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) but instead of basing the new branch on `S` I want to base it on the current `master`.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690187/how-to-git-backport-rebase-cherry-pick-an-already-merged-branch) this solution should work:

> `git rebase --onto stable D fix/123`
>   This is still kind of risky because you need to take the SHA of D (and NOT X for instance).

So I tried `git rebase --no-ff --onto master S feature` but it just advanced the `feature` label to the `master` label and said "Fast-forwarded feature to master" without generating any new commits.

So how can I basically copy the whole `feature` branch on top of master?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that? The commits A-C are already within the history, so copying them at the top of master would duplicate them, possibly confusing everyone looking at it. Instead you might want to apply a fix on the branch (to make it accepted on master) and then merge it again into master.

Comment: They have been reverted some time ago (commit `R`, just like Linus describes in the linked text), so I need to merge them again after some modifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git cherry-pick` now supports a range of commits, like so:

```
git cherry-pick S..C
```

This will get the commits *after* S up through C. You can also specify to start from the *parent* of A, like so:

```
git cherry-pick A^..C
```

Comment: You can also specify a commit range for `git cherry-pick` so you won’t miss any.