# Git - coworker somehow overwrote my entire commit while resolving a conflict

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-cherry-pick

This is what he says he did:

> There was a merge conflict so I chose mine.

What I'm seeing is that my changes are totally gone. The commit is there, but if I go on GitHub and click 'history' for the file, there's nothing showing that my changes were ever there. I found the guilty commit but all it says about it is:

```
Conflicts:
        .../<file>.js
```

What I saw that looked fishy is the commit is titled:

```
Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/development' into devenv
```

But `development` is our remote branch, so I'm guessing he merged to his local branch, goofed it up, and then accidentally pushed his local branch to `development`.

Would this cause the behavior I described? Any ideas on a clean way to fix this?

Edit: So it looks like a `cherry-pick` fixed the problem, I still don't quite get how it got into this state though. I couldn't find any evidence of a force push (Git not Star Wars).

Comment: Ask if he had to a force push (`-f`) to resolve his situation.

Comment: He says he didn't, he does his stuff through his IDE too, I'm only familiar with the console. I looked at his command history and didn't see it there. Lots of `git push -u development` though. If he did this while on his branch could that cause this?

Comment: if at some point your commit was pushed, meaning, you saw the individual commit in GitHub then only a force push could have erased it.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant and beat him if he did )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing just disappears in Git. You can do one of the following:

1. Undo the merge on development branch. [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)
2. Cherry-pick your last commit (with all your contributions) from the history. [How-to git backport (rebase/cherry-pick) an already merged branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690187/how-to-git-backport-rebase-cherry-pick-an-already-merged-branch)