# Multi-Version Code Support in Git

Tags: sql, git, version-control, version, versioning

I have been working on a big SQL based project that is taking an increasing amount of time and effort to maintain its versions.  Lets keep it simple.  I have three folders for each version of the code called Ver1, Ver2, and Ver3.  All three version folders have the exact same filenames within it, but their content differs from version to version.  If I make a change to a particular file in Ver3 that exists in Ver2 and Ver1, how can I use Git not to necessarily make the same changes in those other versions (not always practical due to partial rewrites for performance or logic changes), but to let me know that the other two versions of the file need to be updated in order to catchup to the Ver3? If Git isn't suited for this task, or if you have any experience with a similar issue, I would much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Relevant: [How do I backport a commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440181/how-do-i-backport-a-commit-in-git)